# Android app crashes on setText()

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app but i have a crash on a setText()

this is my java :

```
EditText eText;
TextView chat;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hitch);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    chat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat);
    eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            chat.setText(eText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_hitch"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.mohamad.hitch.Hitch"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_hitch">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edittext" />

<TextView
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/chat" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/input"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.mohamad.hitch, PID: 2415
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtualm ethod 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null    object reference at com.example.mohamad.hitch.Hitch$1.onClick(Hitch.java:41)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I saw that a lot of other people had the same problem but when i tried each solution none of them worked.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: Check your stacktrace and post it here if you still need help. But most likely, one or more of those views don't exist in activity_hitch.xml

Comment: Can you show in xml, where is your `edittext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `EditText` id is editText, not edittext.
Case sensitive !

change to :

```
eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the ID set correctly on the EditText in your XML.  If you show us your full XML file and the error you are receiving it will be easier to find the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it say what the error message is?
Most likely, either `chat` is null or `eText` is null.
Put a break point at `chat.setText(eText.getText().toString());` and see what each value is.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:id="@+id/editText"
```

The id of edit text is : editText not edittext change the eText variable to :

```
 eText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Answer (score 0):

but this ""+ before

```
chat.setText(""+eText.getText().toString());
```

and the ID of the EditText in XML file is editText
and in your java code is edittext . just fix that it will be work.